# Using a UIPageViewController view.size.height is wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a `UIPageViewController` to display a photo gallery type app.

One photo per page with swiping between each.

When the `UIPageViewController` first appears (i.e. from tapping a photo in the gallery view) the status bar hides.

This is correct, except on the first `UIViewController` that gets shown (i.e. the root view controller) inside `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` the `self.view.height` is short by 20 points (i.e. the height of the status bar).

It only affects the initial view controller. When I rotate the view controller and re-layout the interface (using AutoLayout) it all works fine and the height is back to what it should be.

If I get rid of the `UIPageViewController` it all works fine.

In my `UIPageViewController` I'm doing this...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.modelController.event = self.event;

    PhotoViewController *initialController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:self.initialIndex storyboard:self.storyboard];

    [self setViewControllers:@[initialController]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO
                  completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                  }];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

Then in PhotoViewController...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.commentTopLayoutConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height;
    self.commentHeightLayoutConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height - TOP_SPACING;

    self.embeddedCommentView.hidden = NO;

    if (self.imageView.image == nil) {
        [self configureView];
    }
}
```

This should make the `commentView.height` equal to the view height minus 60 and then push the comment view down so that it disappears off the bottom of the screen.

This works on all view controllers (i.e. the other pages) except for the first one.

If I auto-rotate it works. Just on the initial load.

Comment: did u ever figure this out? I have a similar issue.